# laravel updating one to one relationship with model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have 1 to 1 model (model1 <-1---1->model1.0) and i have model2.0 like below:

```php
+------+         +---------+
|      |    +--1-+model1.0 |
|model1+-1--+    +---------+
|      |                    +----------+
+------+                    |model2.0  |
                            +----------+
```

Parent model:

```php
model1 class: { $this->HasOne(ChildModel::class); }
```

Child Model:

```php
model1.0 class: {$this->belongsTo(Model1::class); }
```

Questions: how do i swing from model1.0 to model 2.0? like below:

```php
+------+         +---------+
|      |         |model1.0 |
|model1+-1--+    +---------+
|      |    |               +----------+
+------+-   +-------------1-|model2.0  |
                            +----------+
```

note:

- model1 and model1.0 is in database but model2.0 is still in controller as object variable.
- model1.0 and model2.0 is object of the same model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) part of the documentation:

> ### Belongs To Relationships
>
> When updating a `belongsTo` relationship, you may use the `associate`
>   method. This method will set the foreign key on the child model:
>
> ```php
> $account = App\Account::find(10);
>
> $user->account()->associate($account);
>
> $user->save();
> ```
>
> When removing a `belongsTo` relationship, you may use the `dissociate`
>   method. This method will set the relationship's foreign key to `null`:
>
> ```php
> $user->account()->dissociate();
>
> $user->save();
> ```

So, you can just do this:

```php
/** Delete the relationship */
// get your model1.0 object
$model1_0 = ChildModel::find($id_1);
// delete the relationship between Model1.0 and Model1
$model1_0->relation()->dissociate();
$model1_0->save();

/** Create the new relationship */
// get your model2.0 object
$model2_0 = ChildModel::find($id_2);
// get your model1 object
$model1 = Model1::find($id);
// relate the models
$model2_0->relation()->associate($model1);
$model2_0->save();
```

Pd: I'm assuming that `relation()` is the name of the relationship defined in the child model.

**ChildModel.php**

```php
public function relation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Model1::class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i dont want to delete model1_0 - so when I do `$model1_0->relation()->dissociate();` will it delete the record in database?

Comment: No, it will just set to `null` the foreign key stored in the `Model1.0` object.

Comment: i did: model1->model10()->dissociate() but i receive: `BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne::disassociate()'`

Comment: ohh, you telling me i should dissociate from the child model?

Comment: `dissociate()` needs to be called in the child object.

Comment: @AnD indeed. `associate()` and `dissociate()` are methods provided by the `belongsTo` object.  If you want to do it from the parent object you should use `save()`/`delete()`.

Comment: i tried it in artisan tinker, when i did save() it tells true, but i check in DB nothing happen

Comment: from the child model? that's weird. Check your code line by line.

Comment: is it possible because of php artisan tinker? i did it from child model, and no error but it didn't set null on the foreign key - weird...

Comment: Read [this article](https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/introducing-the-one-to-one-relationship/), it can help you understand better this relationship. Of course, also the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) regarding this aspect.

Comment: ok i got it, but 1 question, can it be done from parent model? because i have the parent model - yes i can query the child model, but it cost 1 action